# Pass 1 or multiple arrays via one parameter to function

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I experience different behaviour if I pass 1 or multiple arrays via one parameter to a function:

Function call:

```
#Case #1: 2 array's
$rankarray1 = @('subtest1','subtest2')
$rankarray2 = @('subtest3','subtest4')
$viz += Add-swcVizSubGraph […]-Rank $rankarray1,$rankarray2 […]

#Case #2: 1 array
$rankarray3 = @('test1','end')
$viz = Add-swcVizBody […] -rank $rankarray3
```

Snippet of function `Add-swcVizSubGraph`/`Add-swcVizBody`:

```
$p_rank = $null
foreach ($rankrequest in $rank) {
    $RankOnLine = $rankgrequest -join " "
    $p_rank += "{rank=same $($RankOnLine )} `n"
}
```

For Case#1 I get as expected both arrays, which I can access individually by index:

```
$rank[0]
Output:
subtest1
subtest2

$rank[1]
Output:
subtest3
subtest4
```

For Case#2 however, the passed array is treated just as one array (which I can actually understand):

```
$rank
Output:
test1
end
```

**Question:** Is there a best practice how to pass 1 or n arrays and treat it the same way in the function?

Comment: If your functions expect an array of arrays use the array constrution operator when passing a single array: `Add-swcVizBody -rank ,$rankarray3`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the "Array construction Operator" (',')  

This way it's working as expected:  

`$rankarray1 = @('subtest1','subtest2')`  `$rankarray2 = @('subtest3','subtest4')`  

`$rankarray3 = ,@('test1','end')`  

Unfortunately I Need to treat it a Little bit different if there is 1 or n Arrays, maybe I'll come up with something new, but currently ist working fine.  

Thanks  Ansgar